# Possible Python `exec` equivalent in C++

Tags: python, c++, exec

I have found a need to execute C++ code in the terminal. When giving thought on how to do this, Python's `exec` command is perfect. Sadly, I cannot use this as I need a C++ parallel.

Is there a similar command in C++?

Comment: No. C++ is generally compiled, not interpreted.

Comment: Would it be possible to have the code compiled based on a command? Like send `g++ filename` and mandate an `enter` keypress?

Comment: You can certainly have your python program generate C++ code, write it to a file, then invoke `g++` to compile it, and then presuming that everything goes well, execute it. But that sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the real problem you're trying to solve. No, not the one about executing C++ code dynamically, but the problem to which the solution you believe is to execute C++ code dynamically.

Comment: Coming from a background of C programming, one would fork the process, and `execvp` within it. Something like https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/177377 could work for launching an executable. If this is what you're asking for?

Comment: [`std::system()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) may come close to what you need, but [isn't always recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19913446/10957435).

Comment: Are you asking for an interactive C++ environment where you can type code and see the result immediately without compiling, just for debug or experiment use,  like ipython or irb?

Comment: @Cygnus  I don't understand how the accepted answer could possibly answer your question. There is no way to execute code dynamically using C++'s `system` or any of the non-standard functions in the `exec*` family. Those are used to run external commands. Python's `exec` is not. It injects code into a running program.

Comment: @TedLyngmo As @Chipster stated in his/her answer - there is no perfect equivalent. The answer given was the closest to `exec` in Python.

Comment: @Cygnus It's just that none of those suggestions can be used to do anything remotely close  to what `exec` in python does and anyone searching for a Python `exec` equivalent in C++ is going to waste time trying to figure out how to use the answer. At least put some example Python `exec`-using code in the question so it becomes clear in what situations the answer can help for future readers, because I can't think of any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no perfect equivalent of `exec()` in C++ that I'm aware, as C++ isn't designed to be used this way normally.

[`system()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system) comes to mind as a near equivalent off the top of my head, although I will warn you that [`system()` is not usually recommended for use in production code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19913446/10957435).

However, if none of the reasons in the linked question bother you, you could theoretically construct an `exec()` from a combination of `system()` and [`exit()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit):

```
void exec(const char* command, int code=0) {
    system(command);
    exit(code);
}
```

---

Edit: I may be way off. [There may be an exec in C++](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/exec-family-of-functions-in-c/). Also, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5631229/10957435).

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no, c++ doesn't have support for evaluating and executing arbitrary code.

If you need scripting support user a scripting language. [Lua](https://github.com/ThePhD/sol2) and [python](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/index.html) are reasonably easy to integrate. [chaiscript](http://chaiscript.com/) even looks a lot like c++ code.

You could invoke a compiler from within your program and then run the resulting executable but i doubt that's a good solution to whatever your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec

> **exec(object[, globals[, locals]])**
>   This function supports dynamic execution of Python code.

There is no equivalent or similar function in C++.